# Plots.jl "WARNING: No strict ticks found"

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I frequently get the following warning message when using Plots.jl:

```
WARNING: No strict ticks found
```

What does this mean?

---

MWE: `plot(x->1/x,0,1)`

Comment: Your MWE does not reproduce the error on my system. Are you on an old version?

Comment: Yep, I still have julia 0.5. Sorry I didn't mention that from the beginning.

Comment: Ah OK, Plots doesn't officially support that, though old Plots versions in metadata will still install on your system. Expect some (more) bugs, though.

Comment: All right. I guess I should finally switch from relying on apt to update my julia version to installing it manually.

Comment: It's worth the while, Plots 0.6 is really great

Comment: Can someone explain what the error means though? I keep getting this on a column of floats and can't figure out how to work around it.

Comment: This message likely appears when trying to plot some unusual values like Inf (1/0 in the MWE) or NaN.